# String builder replace elements at even indexes in string

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

I am trying to replace even incidences in a string with their ASCII value. I'm using the StringBuilder replace method, starting at the index per iteration, ending at the same index, and replacing the value with the ASCII value. For some reason the replace method is not replacing the element at the index with the ASCII value.

`sb` is my StringBuilder holding the string; `result` is my desired returned string.

```java
for (int i =0; i < sb.length(); i=i+2) {
     char c = sb.charAt(i);
     int n = c;
     String a = String.valueOf(n);
     sb.replace(sb.charAt(i), sb.charAt(i), a);
     result = sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: When altering the replace statement to (i + 1, i + 1, a) there is no change in the string output... On the other hand when i alter the statement to (i, i +1, a) the result is a change in every element in the string, not the even incidences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things I will correct, but @Nikolai Dmitriev already pointed some of them out.

1. The `n` is needed, even though @Nikolai Dmitriev said it's not. Since you want to replace it with its ASCII value. However, you can shorten it to `String a = String.valueOf((int) c);` or even get rid of the `c` and just straight up use `String a = String.valueOf((int) sb.charAt(i));
2. You are using `sb.replace(char start, char end, String str);` while the function should accept `sb.replace(int start, int end, String str);`. To correct this, just use `sb.replace(i, i + 1, a);`. Notice that you use `end = i + 1` because the StringBuilder replace function end value is exclusive (not including).
3. Initialize `result` at the end. The variable has a scope of inside the for loop if you do it inside, and since you want to return it, you would want to initialized it after you finish replacing all even-indices.

Comment: After more testing the fix listed above still yields the wrong result. When the replace statement is set to (i, i+1, a), every element in the string gets replaced, not the even elements.

Comment: You have to check that it is an even index by using `if (i % 2 == 0)` and then do the things inside that if statement. :)

Comment: I have done that in two ways, one by incrementing the loop iterations by 2 (i = i + 2) and by throwing in the if condition you just mentioned. Still yields the same result of the whole string being changed, not the even elements :/

Comment: okay, i think i know why that happens. The first one gets changed, and now the second letter will be at index 2, since the ascii value has length 2. Try using a string as your reference, and have an empty stringbuilder at first. Loop through the string, not the stringbuilder, and add the character of the string to the stringbuilder if the index is odd or else add the ascii value

Comment: That was it! thanks for all of the help!! The thought of the index being pushed because of the extra digit didnt even cross my mind lol :)